# My code in TextChanged event breaks binding in WPF - and causes very odd behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, visual-studio-2012

In my VS 2012 WPF project, I have a customized textbox class called `TextBoxDX` that adds an `AutoSelect` feature.  No problem.  I have another class based on `TextBoxDX` called IntBox which only allows integers.  That's where our story begins.  Both classes are used in binding situations like so:

```
<local:TextBoxDX Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtBox_singlesName" Width="320" HorizontalAlignment="left" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.name, ElementName=listBoxSingles, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<local:IntBox x:Name="intBox_heightin" Width="60" AllowZeroValue="True" MaxLength="2" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.heightin, ElementName=listBoxSingles, Mode=OneWay}" MinVal="0" MaxVal="11"/>
```

Pretty sure most of that is irrelevant except for the binding.  Both work fine in that they change their text corresponding to `ListBox` selections.  But in the `IntBox` class, I had to add code for allowing only integers.  In order to do that, I tapped into the `TextChanged` event in my `IntBox` class.  The end result is this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

 namespace Herculese
{
public class IntBox : TextBoxDX
{
    //INIT PROPERTIES
    private int _MaxVal = 0;
    private int _MinVal = 0;
    private bool _AllowZeroValue = false;

    //INIT STRING TO KEEP TRACK OF TEXT BEFORE CHANGES
    private string originalText;

    public IntBox()
    {
        //ADD TO TEXTCHANGED HANDLER
        TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(My_OnTextChanged);

        //STORE ORIGINAL TEXT
        originalText = this.Text;
    }

    //EVENT HANDLER WHEN TEXT IS CHANGED

    private void My_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //IF THERE IS TEXT IN THE BOX,
        MessageBox.Show("yee");
        if (this.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            //REMOVE SPACES AND LEADING ZEROS FROM STRING
            if (!_AllowZeroValue)
                this.Text = this.Text.TrimStart('0');
            this.Text = Regex.Replace(this.Text, @"\s+", "");

            //IF VALUE ISN'T NUMERICAL OR NOTHING IS LEFT AFTER REMOVING ZEROS AND SPACES, CHANGE TEXT BACK TO ORIGINAL
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            if (regex.IsMatch(this.Text) || this.Text.Length < 1)
            {
                this.Text = originalText;
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            }
            //IF VALUE IS NUMERICAL,
            else
            {
                //MAKE SURE VALUE IS WITHIN ACCEPTED RANGE. IF NOT, CHANGE IT TO HIGHEST/LOWEST AVAILABLE RESPECTIVELY
                int intText;
                intText = Convert.ToInt32(this.Text);
                if (intText > _MaxVal)
                {
                    this.Text = _MaxVal.ToString();
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                }
                else if (intText < _MinVal)
                {
                    this.Text = _MinVal.ToString();
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                }
                //SUCCESS!  UPDATE ORIGINAL TEXT WITH NEW VALID VALUE.
                else originalText = this.Text;
            }
        }
    }

    //PROVIDE GET/SET PROPERTIES
    public int MaxVal
    {
        get { return _MaxVal; }
        set { _MaxVal = value; }
    }
    public int MinVal
    {
        get { return _MinVal; }
        set { _MinVal = value; }
    }
    public bool AllowZeroValue
    {
        get { return _AllowZeroValue; }
        set { _AllowZeroValue = value; }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I had a great time in the `TextChanged` of my `IntBox`.  Wild parties, you name it.  Suddenly I realized that binding for `IntBox` wasn't working anymore.  I could manually change the text just fine.  It only accepted integers and worked like a charm.  But changing the `ListBox` selection no longer updated the text.  If I removed the code in `My_OnTextChanged`, the binding worked again.  I figured my code was causing the problem.  So I came back today with a fresh head and realized something weird.

If I remove the code in `My_OnTextChanged` and replace it with a `MessageBox`, the binding works and the message box appears.  Makes perfect sense and furthers the idea that my code is causing the issue.  Now for the weirdness:  if I put the code back into the event after the `MessageBox` code, binding is broken again and the `MessageBox` never shows meaning the event never fires. All I can say to that is... HUUUUH?!  I've recreated this several times just to be sure I'm not crazy. The only other thing I could think of is a conflict with the `TextBoxDX` that it inherits from so I made it inherit directly from `TextBox` and got the same results... Anybody got a clue on this one?

Comment: _meaning the event never fires_- Did you try placing a breakpoint to *make sure* it isn't called?

Comment: The Binding is not broken, you have just replaced it by assining a Value to `this.Text`

Comment: @Blachshma confirmed with breakpoint, event does not fire.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 this.Text only gets a value under certain "if" circumstances.  the values that are being loaded into the boxes do not trigger those circumstances, I've made sure.  EDIT: Scratch that, I see what you mean thanks to your post below... going to try that right now, thank you!

Comment: But anytime you change the value of the Text to anything other than string.Empty, this code will run `this.Text = Regex.Replace(this.Text, @"\s+", "");` this will replace the binding.
`

Comment: Yeah, I changed that all the "this.text=" as well as used a temporary string variable for the regex.replace.  Much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a new value to `Text` which is removing the original binding as you have replaced it with a new string.

Instead of using `this.Text = "Somthing"` try using `base.SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, value);`

Example:

```
//IF VALUE ISN'T NUMERICAL OR NOTHING IS LEFT AFTER REMOVING ZEROS AND SPACES, CHANGE TEXT BACK TO ORIGINAL
Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
if (regex.IsMatch(this.Text) || this.Text.Length < 1)
{
    // this.Text = originalText;

    base.SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, originalText);
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
}
```

`SetCurrentValue` Sets the value of a dependency property without changing its value source.

Comment: Worked great, thanks!  Should have been obvious how I was breaking the binding considering I was basically saying ok, text=whatever in xaml then contradicting that later.  First time the event ran (on loading a data file in this case), it loaded the values in and THAT'S when it was breaking the bind, before I ever got a chance to try changing the selection.  You can chalk all this up to the fact that I've never databound textboxes before.  This will actually fix a couple other issues I had to work around in my code now that i know the right way.  Mystery solved.  Thank you very much!